# Is there a device that allows a USB Device to become as wireless one

Tags: networking, usb, wireless-keyboard

I'm asking this here as it relates to the setup of my Game Lab.

In my lab, i am going to connect my widescreen TV to my computer via HDMI however, due to the positioning of my computer i need a 6m HDMI Cable to connect them (because of the setup of new power points, should have had a say in it insted of relaying on my parents), anyway, this is a round look of the room

```
|-----------------|
|   [ TV ]       _|
|                 
|                 |
|[  COUCH  ]  [PC]|
|-----------------|
```

now, what i want to do is to be able to do my gaming on the TV in a bigger screen, i have already tested out some games in my current room and i know they are improved on it (Shikkoku no Sharnoth ~What a Beautiful Tomorrow~, Fallout, Skyrim)

now i have a wireless gaming mouse but the keyboard i have (which i am keeping) isn't wireless and neither is my PS3 Controller.

So i am wondering if there is a device that turns a USB Device into a wireless one, if one does exist what is it called cause when i think of these kind of things i don't normally have the right name to search for them

you can post links of where i can buy but i am mainly asking for the existence of this device and what it is called so i can find it myself

Comment: A device must be designed to be wireless to be wireless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple devices out there that seem to do what you want, most of them are designed for industrial or commercial use however, and are likely outside of any price range you would be willing to spend.

http://www.kvms.com/Product/EXT-WUSB.aspx

http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=5529

Comment: dam, seems like they need a power supply from the wall, was thinking they may be like my old wireless mouse, the transmitter gets power from the PC while the receiver (in the mouse) is powered by batteries and i already have 5 points in my powerboard taken (Computer, Main Screen, 2.1 Speakers, Main Work Portable Harddrive, SATA USB Dock) and the Harddrive thanks to those bloody wings Australian Plugs always have blocks the 6th, still, i have the name of the device which means i can always keep my eyes open, thanks